# How can I find the type of the values in a Map?

Tags: java, dictionary, types

If have something like this:

```
public abstract class Animal {...}

public class Dog extends Animal {...}

public class Cat extends Animal {...}

Map<Integer, Animal> dogs = getSomeDogs(); 
Map<Integer, Animal> cats = getSomeCats(); 

private Map<Integer, Dog> specificDogs;
public Map<Integer, Dog> specificallyGetSomeDogs(); 
{
    return this.specificDogs;
}
```

You see have a method `getSomeDogs()` that is returning generic `Map<Integer, Animal>` objects.

My method `specificallyGetSomeDogs()` needs to return a `Map<Integer, Dog>`.

How can I convert the result from `getSomeDogs()` into a `Map<Integer, Dog>`?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can trust your `getSomeDogs()` method to always return `Map<Integer, Dog>`, so you can do:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Map<Integer, Dog> specificallyGetSomeDogs()
{
    Map<Integer, Dog> result = new HashMap<Integer, Dog>();
    Map map = getSomeDogs();
    result.putAll(map);
    return result;
}
```

Otherwise, you would do:

```
public Map<Integer, Dog> specificallyGetSomeDogs()
{
    Map<Integer, Dog> result = new HashMap<Integer, Dog>();
    Map<Integer, Animal> map = getSomeDogs();
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Animal> integerAnimalEntry : map.entrySet()) {
        result.put(integerAnimalEntry.getKey(), (Dog) integerAnimalEntry.getValue());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
animals.forEach((Integer integer, Animal animal) -> dogs.put(
                        integer, (Dog) animal));
```

animals is a Map.
dogs is a Map.
This only works in JDK8.

**EDIT**: For JDK6, use the following code:

```
animals.forEach(new BiConsumer<Integer, Animal>() {
    public void accept(Integer integer, Animal animal) {
        dogs.put(integer, animal); // You may have to make dogs final
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using JDK6... :(

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
    Map<Integer, Dog> specificDogs= new HashMap<Integer, Dog>();

    Iterator it = dogs.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();          

        specificDogs.put((Integer)pair.getKey(), (Dog)pair.getValue());        

    }
```